# Java Metrics Sample code

Tags: java, metrics

I am newbie to metrics and I don't understand why I am getting this output Please somebody explain. Thanks in advance.

```
package sample;
  import com.codahale.metrics.*;
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

  public class GetStarted {
    static final MetricRegistry metrics = new MetricRegistry();
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      startReport();
      Meter requests = metrics.meter("requests");
      requests.mark();
      wait5Seconds();
    }

  static void startReport() {
      ConsoleReporter reporter = ConsoleReporter.forRegistry(metrics)
          .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
          .build();
      reporter.start(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  static void wait5Seconds() {
      try {
          Thread.sleep(5*1000);
      }
      catch(InterruptedException e) {}
  }
}
```

Output :

12/18/15 12:01:15 PM ===========================================================

-- Meters ----------------------------------------------------------------------
requests
             count = 1
         mean rate = 1.00 events/second
     1-minute rate = 0.00 events/second
     5-minute rate = 0.00 events/second
    15-minute rate = 0.00 events/second

12/18/15 12:01:16 PM ===========================================================

-- Meters ----------------------------------------------------------------------
requests
             count = 1
         mean rate = 0.50 events/second
     1-minute rate = 0.00 events/second
     5-minute rate = 0.00 events/second
    15-minute rate = 0.00 events/second

12/18/15 12:01:17 PM ===========================================================

-- Meters ----------------------------------------------------------------------
requests
             count = 1
         mean rate = 0.33 events/second
     1-minute rate = 0.00 events/second
     5-minute rate = 0.00 events/second
    15-minute rate = 0.00 events/second

12/18/15 12:01:18 PM ===========================================================

-- Meters ----------------------------------------------------------------------
requests
             count = 1
         mean rate = 0.25 events/second
     1-minute rate = 0.00 events/second
     5-minute rate = 0.00 events/second
    15-minute rate = 0.00 events/second

12/18/15 12:01:19 PM ===========================================================

-- Meters ----------------------------------------------------------------------
requests
             count = 1
         mean rate = 0.20 events/second
     1-minute rate = 0.00 events/second
     5-minute rate = 0.00 events/second
    15-minute rate = 0.00 events/second

Comment: Can you share what was your expectation for the output?

Comment: Are you confused by the fact that on the one hand you see ´requests count=1` and on the other some of your rates are `0.00` ? Have a look at [`mark()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.codahale.metrics/metrics-core/3.0.0/com/codahale/metrics/Meter.java#Meter.mark%28%29), it increases the count by 1 already.

Comment: @RajnikantPatel I am learning newly. I just want to understand how im getting this output.

Comment: @Marged Yes . and also wat is 1 min rate and 15 min rate.

Comment: @Marged Could you help me by sharing some tutorial links or some resource to learn metrics.

Comment: Obviously you already know the getting started guide. There is a nice presentation on slideshare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After creating registry, you have started the reporter with 1 second interval. So for each second, your console reporter will output to console.

You have chosen meter type metric which will give you count(no of times this event occurred) and mean rate (average rate). Other rates will be zero because a single time unit of that measurement is not yet over. Eg. You ran the program only for 5 seconds so you will not get 1 minute rate. Let it run for more than 1 minute you can see other rates with some value.

```
requests.mark();
```

The above line is used to mark the occurrence of an event. As you have invoked it once a metric event will be triggered. As you are not calling this method any more in the program, so count remains 1.

mean rate is (total count from start of application)/(total time in secs from start). Note: here it is seconds. For every second reporter is printing. As count=1, at 1st sec rate= (1 count)/(1sec). at 2nd sec rate = (1 count)/(2 sec)=0.5 , at 3rd sec rate = (1 count)/(3 sec) = 0.33

1 min rate is (total count in last 1 min)/(60 secs). 1 min rates here it is zero because still 1 minute has not passed. Same for the following big interval rates

5 min rate is (total count in last 5 min)/(5*60 secs) . 5 mins = 5*60 secs

You might expect the thread to sleep and thereby expecting a gap of 5 secs in the log. But the reporter is running in a different thread. So here sleeping for 5 secs is of no value except make the program run to 5 seconds.

Comment: can you accept the answer if it makes sense and is understandable

Comment: Could you help me by sharing some tutorial links or some resource to learn metrics.

Comment: Thanks . Apart from this.

Comment: getting started section of dropwizard link above contains most of the required stuff. what is it you want to know more about?

Comment: I am going through the dropwizard link already but not able understanding properly. So looking for some detailed example programs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98329/discussion-between-aradhya-and-prem-kumar).